# Heroku deploy Cannot / Get

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy my MEAN application to Heroku. The deploy is successful but when i am opening my applicaton i get an error CANNOT / GET. When i check the console the followings i get
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ztHp.png).

I have tried to configure the package.json several times but it didnot help. You can check it from my commits.

Here is my github repo.: https://github.com/urgyanmiki/AngularApp

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json is starting the server.js of your backend. But you don't have a server.js for your frontend to receive requests. 
I would suggest that you split your apps and deploy two apps to Heroku to see if everything is working. Afterwards you can still combine them into one app if you like.

You can follow this example to see what Heroku expects for the server.js of your frontend: [Medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/using-heroku-to-deploy-an-angular-app-5be838ef1de7)